# Finding output history on JupyterLab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Trying to find the output history for a particular Jupyter Notebook. I tried `%hist -o -g -f ipython_history.md` but this only got me the input history. Is there any way to get the output history on JupyterLab?

Comment: (note that the answers describe how to get output of any previously executed cell)

Comment: Did you want to be able to see the history one particular cell at a time--then the question linked above should help you--or did you want a way to get the whole output history at once? I'm thinking the latter, and I'm hoping someone will know the answer.

Comment: @joanis what would be an example use case of getting entire output history? (just being curious here).

Comment: Dumping all the output to a file, for example, similarly to OP's example dumping all the inputs to a file. I'm just trying to clarify the question so someone could answer it more effectively.

Comment: I've asked the question again - in a more clear way